# Need to add a couple of items to this sql on IBM i

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

In the first part we selected some records and created an 'outfile' using the Session options for file output. I would like both parts to be one SQL. In Part 2. I have to include column of the last table. ad.IARCC9 the data result currently is this: data is showing the part# sold according to dates we just need that last col included which is the referral to the vendor.

```
QUANTITY       WWDOCD   PART NO.           
    1.00   20,121,205   MYAABC             
    1.00   20,130,619   MYAABC             
    1.00   20,130,619   MYAABC             
    1.00   20,130,726   MYAABC             
   25.00   20,120,629   AC-GL9             
   20.00   20,120,502   AC-GL9             
   30.00   20,120,425   AC-GL9             
   30.00   20,120,419   AC-GL9             
   20.00   20,120,411   AC-GL9             
   30.00   20,120,321   AC-GL9
```

Part 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM astccdta.Oeinh48 a
JOIN astdta.IcDet1 b ON b.Itcom# = a.IhCom# AND b.ItTrn# = a.IhIdc#
WHERE A.IHORDD > 20120101 AND b.ItTscc = 'I'
--------
```

Part 2.

```
SELECT ItQty#,IhDocd,ItPRT#
FROM pklib.Fileout1 a
JOIN astdta.icEct1 b ON b.CtCom# = a.ItCom# AND b.CtCtr# = ' ' AND b.CtPrt# =a.ItPrt#
JOIN astdta.Audia ad ON ad.IAprt# = a.ItPrt#
WHERE ad.IARCC9 > ''
ORDER BY ad.IARCC9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track in trying to avoid a temporary intermediate outfile.

The tool you want in your arsenal is called a [common table expression](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzcomtexp.htm) [CTE]. This a powerful technique that allows you build a complex [SELECT statement](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintsel.htm) as a series of logical building blocks.

Yours can be put together like this:

```
with f as
(
  SELECT *
    FROM astccdta.Oeinh48  a
    JOIN astdta.IcDet1     b   ON   b.Itcom# = a.IhCom#
                               AND b.ItTrn# = a.IhIdc#
    WHERE A.IHORDD > 20120101
      AND b.ItTscc = 'I'
)
SELECT ItQty#,IhDocd,ItPRT#
  FROM f     -- this refers to the result set of the CTE above
  JOIN astdta.icEct1  b   ON  b.CtCom# = f.ItCom#
                          AND b.CtPrt# = f.ItPrt#
                          AND b.CtCtr# = ' ' 
  JOIN  astdta.Audia  d   ON  d.IAprt# = f.ItPrt#
  WHERE a.IARCC9 > ''
  ORDER BY d.IARCC9;
```

---

Additional note:  Rather than use the STRSQL session options, you can easily use SQL itself to create an outfile.   Just put a little wrapper around your query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE fileout as
(
   -- your query goes here
)
WITH DATA;
```

Or if you wanted to add to an existing file

```
INSERT INTO fileout
   -- your query goes here
;
```

By using SQL to write your results, rather than session settings, you have created a solution that can be run from other interfaces.